# method, Partial-Fraction Decomposition. $-\int \frac{8x^8}{x^8-5x^7+15x^6-37x^5+65x^4-87x^3+93x^2-63x+18}dx$

Tags: integration

I have solve it. 
method, Partial-Fraction Decomposition.

$$-\int \frac{8x^8}{x^8-5x^7+15x^6-37x^5+65x^4-87x^3+93x^2-63x+18}dx$$

Solution.

$$-8\int \frac{x^8}{(x-1)^3(x-2)(x^2+3)^2}dx$$

$$\frac{x^8}{(x-1)^3(x-2)(x^2+3)^2}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{(x-1)^3}+\frac{D}{x-2}+\frac{Fx+G}{x^2+3}+\frac{Hx+I}{(x^2+3)^2}$$

$$x^8=A(x-1)^2(x-2)(x^2+3)^2+B(x-1)(x-2)(x^2+3)^2+C(x-2)(x^2+3)^2+D(x-1)^3(x^2+3)^2+(Fx+G)(x-1)^3(x-2)(x^2+3)+(Hx+I)(x-1)^3(x-2)$$

then,

For $x=1$ ,  $C=-\frac{1}{16}$

For $x=2$,  $D=\frac{256}{49}$

I need help with the other constants, ideas? method?

Comment: Compare the coefficients of the different powers of $x$

Comment: use this here $$1+{\frac {256}{49\,x-98}}-1/16\, \left( x-1 \right) ^{-3}-{\frac {113
}{64\,x-64}}+{\frac {-81\,x-162}{56\, \left( {x}^{2}+3 \right) ^{2}}}-
1/2\, \left( x-1 \right) ^{-2}+{\frac {4833\,x+5697}{3136\,{x}^{2}+
9408}}
$$